# Link Checker / Validator, preferably for automatic builds?

Tags: validation, hyperlink, web-crawler

I am doing some preliminary research into a'link checker' for a (.net) website. The basic idea is that this tool would crawl through the website and check to see if the links in it are functional and lead to a valid page. I've seen some of the posts here, but I am looking for more of a standard tool.

Also If there is any way that this could be part of an automatic build process, that would be great.

Is there a MS / standard tool for this? This seems like it would be common enough ... how do you guys do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could automate link checker (supports command line) with A1 Website Analyzer. But it does not yet have an options for an emergency popup if errors are found :) But it could be added.